# How can I export in R

Tags: r

[image]

Hello,I was trying to use that code https://community.rstudio.com/t/export-rstudio-data-to-excel/7579/4 so I can export this with name nn.csv.
I want to export the Data_passed_slim

Comment: ```readr::write_csv(x = Data_passed_slim, path = "nn.csv")```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Native R: `write.csv(Data_passed_slim, "nn.csv")`.
See `?write.csv` for documentation.

But, for larger datasets I would recommend using `data.table::fwrite()`. Documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.0/topics/fwrite

Comment: it worked but it doesn't show me where it is

Comment: It will be saved in working directory. Use `getwd()` to know where it is or `setwd()` to change it.

Comment: thanks a lot I will 6 minutes to tick it